# getline() not filling the whole string array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote this code to read N lines from console input and put it into array of string, but it's
reading N-1 lines
Any suggestions ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int test;
cin>>test;
string *cases=new string[test];
for(int i=0;i<test;i++)
{
    getline(cin,cases[i],'\n');
}

for(int i=0;i<test;i++)
{
    cout<<cases[i]<<endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: give a sample output explaining what is wrong

Comment: It's the combination of `>>` and `getline`. The rest of the line (which actually probably contains nothing) after you enter the `int` for the size is being read into `cases[0]`. I always find it's simplest just not to mix use of `>>` and `getline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your input is like this:

```
2\n
line 0\n
line 1\n
```

Then after `cin>>test`, there is an empty line at the top:

```
\n
line 0\n
line 1\n
```

Using `>>` only reads the bit it is interested in (i.e. the `int`) then leaves anything else behind on the stream (in this case, just the `\n` but think about it, there might be all kinds of stuff on the line).
`getline` reads everything up to the `\n` **then removes the `\n` from the stream**.
So after the first `getline`, the remaining input is:

```
line 0\n
line 1\n
```

and `cases[0]` contains `""` (i.e. an empty string).

Then after the next `getline`:

```
remaining input:
line 1\n
```

and

```
cases[0]: ""
cases[1]: "line 0"
```

Then the loop stops, because it has read 2 lines.
That's what's wrong. Fixing it is another matter. I prefer just to avoid mixing `>>` and `getline`. But you could do something to clear that trailing `\n` off the stream.

EDIT: You might also do well to read up on [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (that documentation might be a bit technical - search for tutorials) and the evils of [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

I put together one way of fixing it. Note [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is c++11 only. If you don't have that available, you could try a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) with `>>`, or [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int inLines = 0;
    //std::cin >> inLines;
    std::string countLine;
    std::getline(std::cin, countLine);
    try
    {
        inLines = std::stoi(countLine);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "First line must be an integer\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> lines(inLines);

    for (int i = 0; i < inLines; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, lines[i]);
    }

    for ( auto & s : lines )
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem, i fixed it with scanf("%d\n",&test);
Is there a better way ?

Comment: I added one possible way of doing it. Using `scanf` fixes this particular problem, but still basically means you are mixing up your input methods, which can cause trouble.